# Is there a way to get the context of the route being pushed to show a snackbar in it?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a screen that pop all routes and push a new one. At this new screen that is being pushed, I want to show a snackbar, but I'm not being able to make it work.
There is also another part of the application that I'll need to do something similar, but not popping all routes. 
This is how I'm currently trying, but I believe it's not working because I'm not using the context of the new pushed screen:

```
if (something) {
        Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
          context,
          searchRoute,
          (_) => false,
        );

        final snackbar = SnackBar(
          content: Text("Thing done successfully!"),
          backgroundColor: Colors.green[700],
        );

        Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(snackbar);
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
```

That's why I wanna know if there's a way to get the context of the route when I push it with the Navigator, so I can then use it to show the snackbar correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You must use `GlobalKey`, declare `_scaffoldKey` in class like,

```
final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
```

then setup key in your `Scaffold`

```
@override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new Scaffold(
    key: _scaffoldKey,
```

later use,

```
_scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(snackbar);
```

Hope it works.